# Module not found: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' ReactJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working on reactjs (17.0.1) (node v15.11.0)  with typescript and I'm getting this warning message, any idea how solve it ?

```
./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' in '/Users/jorge/Documents/Development/Projects/React-Js/project/node_modules/typescript/lib'
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't know the reason, but perf_hooks has nothing to do with React hooks but is [NodeJS's Performance API](https://nodejs.org/api/perf_hooks.html). Maybe you can try with Node16?

Comment: Is your ReactJS application running in a browser? It won't work then, unfortunately. `perf_hooks` is a Node.js-specific module, browsers don't have it.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell this is still an outstanding issue: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/39436

I get the exact same 3 warnings when I import anything from typescript - ex:

```
import { transpile } from 'typescript';
```

results in:

Compiled with warnings.

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

./node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'perf_hooks' in 'C:\me\myName\GitHub\projectFolder\node_modules\typescript\lib'

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when I was editing a JavaScript code and imported a TypeScript dependency, even if my project was supporting typescript.

Check whether you have any typescript dependency on your javascript file.

Answer (score -1):

I had this same error when working on a Next.JS application with only a frontend and added TS later. I believe it is to do with the NPM TypeScript Node package. I resolved it by running:

```sh
npm i typescript @types/react @types/node
```

to install all the TypeScipt dependencies (including for Node)

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Did you have maybe another solution?

Answer (score -2):

Check to see that your node version is up to date with `node -v`
If it's not you can download the latest LTS at
`https://nodejs.org/en/download/`

After download and installation verify that the latest version is now your default with `node -v` again.
If you're unable to change your node version and have nvm (node version manager) installed you can select `nvm alias default xx.xx.x` (where xx.xx.x is the node version you wish to use as default).